# React Login with Redirect on callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm new to react and struggling to redirect the user in a demo app to a default page after they submit the login form. I'm not entirely sure why `return <Redirect to="/default" />;` isn't doing anything.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-login-form-6y8kj)

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Form from "./Form";
import Default from "./default";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/default" component={Default} />
          <Route path="/" component={Form} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Form.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import useForm from "./useForm";
import validate from "./LoginFormValidationRules";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const Form = () => {
  const { values, errors, handleChange, handleSubmit } = useForm(
    login,
    validate
  );

  function login() {
    console.log("logged in");
    return <Redirect to="/default" />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="section is-fullheight">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="column is-6 is-offset-3">
          <div className="box">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
              <div className="field">
                <label className="label">Email Address</label>
                <div className="control">
                  <input
                    autoComplete="off"
                    className={`input ${errors.email && "is-danger"}`}
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={values.email || ""}
                    required
                  />
                  {errors.email && (
                    <p className="help is-danger">{errors.email}</p>
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="field">
                <label className="label">Password</label>
                <div className="control">
                  <input
                    className={`input ${errors.password && "is-danger"}`}
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={values.password || ""}
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                {errors.password && (
                  <p className="help is-danger">{errors.password}</p>
                )}
              </div>
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="button is-block is-info is-fullwidth"
              >
                Login
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

**useForm.jsx**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useForm = (callback, validate) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({});
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && isSubmitting) {
      callback();
    }
  }, [errors]);

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    if (event) event.preventDefault();
    setErrors(validate(values));
    setIsSubmitting(true);
  };

  const handleChange = event => {
    event.persist();
    setValues(values => ({
      ...values,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }));
  };

  return {
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
    values,
    errors
  };
};

export default useForm;
```

Comment: From where is `login()` called?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi `login()` is the callback function

Comment: So it seems not a full code. I think it is very unfamiliar (at least with me) to return something from callback function.

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi Im still fairly new to react. Visit the CodeSandbox to see the current working version

Comment: `<Redirect to="/default" />` block should be somewhere in `Form/return`. I think...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated my solutions.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import useForm from "./useForm";
import validate from "./LoginFormValidationRules";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const Form = () => {
  const { values, errors, handleChange, handleSubmit } = useForm(
    login,
    validate
  );

  const[loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  function login() {
    console.log("logged in");
    setLoggedIn(true);
    return <Redirect to="/default" />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="section is-fullheight">
      {
        loggedIn && (
          <Redirect to="/default" />
        )
      }
      <div className="container">
        <div className="column is-6 is-offset-3">
          <div className="box">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
              <div className="field">
                <label className="label">Email Address</label>
                <div className="control">
                  <input
                    autoComplete="off"
                    className={`input ${errors.email && "is-danger"}`}
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={values.email || ""}
                    required
                  />
                  {errors.email && (
                    <p className="help is-danger">{errors.email}</p>
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="field">
                <label className="label">Password</label>
                <div className="control">
                  <input
                    className={`input ${errors.password && "is-danger"}`}
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={values.password || ""}
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                {errors.password && (
                  <p className="help is-danger">{errors.password}</p>
                )}
              </div>
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="button is-block is-info is-fullwidth"
              >
                Login
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

But I wanna to say that there are some solutions to implement it.
Above one is the one of them.
please try to use this.